# When does a template end?

Tags: c++

When does a template end?
Let's have a look at this code:

```
template <class T>
class thatClass
{
   T a, b;
   thatClass (T x, T y) {a = x; b = y;}
};

template <class T>T aFunc(T one, T two)
{
   return one+two;
}
```

So when does `template <class T>` end? Does it always end after at the end of a class or function definition or what? And why can't you just use the one template you declared for both classes and functions, so in this case, I could use the template parameter `T` for both the function `aFunc` and for the class definition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The scope of the template parameter ends with the scope of the templated subject:

```
template <class T>
class thatClass
{
   T a, b;
   thatClass (T x, T y) {a = x; b = y;}
}; // << ends here

template <class T>T aFunc(T one, T two)
{
   return one+two;
}  // << ends here
```

> And why can't you just use the one template you declared for both classes and functions, so in this case, I could use the template parameter `T` for both the function `aFunc` and for the class definition?

You can't because template parameter scope is always bound to a class/struct or function definition. That's defined as such in the language.

One could think of templating a whole `namespace`, but that's not an available language feature, and I'm not sure if that would be a good idea at all.

---

As you seem to be confused I'll add some variations:

```
template <class T>
class thatClass
{
   T a, b;
   thatClass (T x, T y) {a = x; b = y;}
   // A member funcion that uses the same template parameter and accesses 
   // the class member variables
   T aFunc() { return a+b; }
   // A static member funcion that uses the same template parameter and
   // calculates the result from the parameters
   static T aStaticFunc(T one, T two) { return one+two; }
 };
```

Comment: Thanks! But what about the last part of my question? The part about why you can't use one template for it all, like using the first T for both "aFunc" and "thatClass"

Comment: @Hei I've picked that up in my answer.

Comment: Thanks! "I'm not sure if that would be a good idea at all.", why wouldn't it?

Comment: @Hei Leaving too much confusion probably.

Comment: Makes sense. One more thing: Can't you just namespace a class and then do all the function definition in there?

Comment: @Hei I don't fully get what you mean? Are you talking about `static` class member functions?

Comment: No. Like you could do this `template <class T>class myClass {T getit (T a, T b) {return a+b;}.. and have all functions and their definitions in here, so they all can access the one template parameter}` so you do not have to have one template for each function definition

Comment: @Hei _"so you do not have to have one template for each function definition"_ It's already like that?? I believe you have some big confusions of how templates actually work.

Comment: I know that this is already how it works... Maybe it was a weird example.. When it is like that, why would you then define functions outside the class if you would have to make another template for that particular function definition? Btw I appreciate your time!

Comment: @Hei Template functions are a realm on their own. You might be interested looking into the [`<algorithm>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm) c++ standard header, and why these are useful outside of any class.

Comment: Thanks! But I just do not see why you would want to repeat writing the template for each function definition(when defining outside the class) rather than just keeping the definition in the already templated class, so you could define all functions without repeating writing `template<class T>` in front of each. So why would you choose do define functions outside the class in such case?

Comment: _" So why would you choose do define functions outside the class in such case?"_ To make them applicable for many (template) classes, like the functions in `<algorithm>` do. Read about [_concepts_](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints)! Open your mind, templates are far more powerful tools like you seem to have grasped so far.

Comment: I have just read about the link you mentioned before and it has helped. I really want you to know that I am thankful for your time!

Comment: _"I am thankful for your time! "_ Don't stretch that overly please. There's a point I could loose patience as it turned out in the past.

Comment: "There's a point I could loose patience as it turned out in the past", what do you mean?

Comment: _"what do you mean?"_ It's my 1st day back here after being banned for 2 months because of _"not being nice"_.

Comment: Well okay then... But I still do not see why you would loose patience after I said that I was thankful? I mean that has nothing to do with patience, has it?

Comment: It's all fine so far. I'm calm. SNAFU! (you may consider I'm getting a lot of pings here)